# Is possible to get logs by date with spring boot actuator?

Tags: spring-boot-actuator

Is there any way to get logs by date with spring boot actuator?

I can retrieve the current logs with the endpoint **/actuator/logfile**

But I would like to get logs by date passing a param in the URL

Do you know if there is a way to achieve this with actuator?